# Estoy teniendo problemas para configurar firebase con un formulario

Tags: firebase, reactjs

mi studentName no se completa al escribir cualquier nombre en el input.
es decir la variable studentName sigue siendo null.
por favor ayuda es mi primer intento usando firebase y pues no se muy bien como hacerlo, desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder, aquí les dejo una imagen de lo que me dice la consola.
disculpen si es una consulta muy básica, seguro es algo sencillo que no me estoy dando cuenta.
estoy escribiendo una descripcion larga porque stackoverflow me dice que añada mas detalles porque sino mi publicacion es practicamente puro codigo pero en realidad no tengo mucho que decir solo que mi variable studentName sigue siendo null.

[image: imagen que muestra lo que dice la consola]

Este es el codigo de mi aplicacion React que estoy usando en el componente Usurvey, espero que se entienda lo que estoy intentando hacer, es de un ejercicio en un curso de Udemy.

```js
import React from 'react';

const firebase = require('firebase');
const uuid = require('uuid');
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAAWzjB3tcxtIABEY_JWAYePbb_v5tJklc",
    authDomain: "u-survey-86e95.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://u-survey-86e95.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "u-survey-86e95",
    storageBucket: "u-survey-86e95.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "336098190372",
    appId: "1:336098190372:web:fe93c31cd986617e"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class Usurvey extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            uid: uuid.v1(),
            studentName: '',
            answers: {
                answer1: '',
                answer2: '',
                answer3: ''
            },
            isSubmited: false
        };
        this.nameSubmit = this.nameSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    nameSubmit(event)
    {
        let studentName = this.refs.name.nodeValue;
        this.setState({studentName: studentName}, function(){
            console.log(this.state);
        });
    }

    render(){
        let studentName;
        let questions;

        if(this.state.studentName === '' && this.state.isSubmited === false)
        {
            studentName = 
            <div>
                <h2>Hey student, please let us know your name:</h2>
                <form onSubmit = {this.nameSubmit}>
                    <input className = "namy" type = "text" placeholder = "Enter your name." ref = "name"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        }

        return(
            <div>
                {studentName}
                <div className = "line">
                 <hr />
                </div>
                {questions}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Usurvey;
```

Comment: Basicamente el problema que tienes es que no te guarda el valor del input en el state?

Comment: si eso mismo es lo que esta pasando, no lo guarda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno intentare explicarte un poco de como prefiero hacero yo y el porque.

Basicamente cuando yo trabajo con `inputs, selects` en react prefiero asignarle a cada input un atributo, que el valor de ese atributo hace referencia a la clave del `state`

Por ejemplo:

```
this.state = {nombre:'' }
```

Entonces yo, desde el input hago referencia e esta clave(nombre).

```
<input
  className = "namy"
  onChange = {
    this.recogerValores
  }
  type = "text"
  data = "nombre" 
  placeholder = "Enter your name."
  ref = "name" / >
```

Entonces como te habras dado cuenta en el atributo `data` tengo puesto el campo o la clave de mi `state` que hace referencia.

Tambien le tengo asignado un metodo `onChange` para cuando cambie el valor de ese input.

Vamos a ver el metodo `recogerValores`

```
 recogerValores(event) {
   //Buscamos el campo al que hace referencia
   let key = event.target.getAttribute('data')
   let valor = event.target.value
   this.setState({[key]: valor })
 }
```

Como ves con este metodo nos sirve para todos los inputs que tenemos, simplemente le tenemos que añadir el atributo data(o con cualquier otro nombre)

Entonces dicho esto, vamos a proceder a  ver que pasa cuando el formulario se envia. He visto que tienes un check(isSubmited) para saber si se ha enviado o no.

```
submitForm(event) {
  //Por ahora no recargamos la pagina.
  event.preventDefault()
  //Procesar los datos...
  //...tu codigo 
  //Finalmente simulamos de que todo ha ido bien.
  this.setState({
    isSubmited: true
  })
}
```

Entonces si damos por acabado la validacion de datos y tal, simplemente le decimos que el formulario ha sido enviado y listo.

Lo otro es que tendras que cambiar la condicion de

```
studentName === "" &&  isSubmited === false
```

por

```
studentName === "" ||  isSubmited === false
```

No me enrollo mas y te dejo el codigo completo.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const firebase = require("firebase");
const uuid = require("uuid");
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAAWzjB3tcxtIABEY_JWAYePbb_v5tJklc",
  authDomain: "u-survey-86e95.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://u-survey-86e95.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "u-survey-86e95",
  storageBucket: "u-survey-86e95.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "336098190372",
  appId: "1:336098190372:web:fe93c31cd986617e"
};
// Initialize Firebase
//firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class Usurvey extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      studentName: "",
      answers: {
        answer1: "",
        answer2: "",
        answer3: ""
      },
      isSubmited: false
    };
    this.recogerValores = this.recogerValores.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  recogerValores(event) {
    //Buscamos el campo al que hace referencia
    let key = event.target.getAttribute('data')
    let valor = event.target.value
    this.setState({[key]: valor })
  }

  submitForm(event) {
    //Por ahora no recargamos la pagina.

    event.preventDefault()
    //Procesar los datos...
    //...tu codigo 

    //Finalmente simulamos de que todo ha ido bien.
    this.setState({isSubmited: true })
  }
  render() {
    let {questions, studentName, isSubmited} = this.state;;

    if (studentName === "" ||  isSubmited === false) {
      studentName = (
        <div>
          <h2>Hey student, please let us know your name:</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
            <input
              className="namy"
              onChange={this.recogerValores}
              type="text"
              data="studentName"
              placeholder="Enter your name."
              ref="name"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {studentName}
        <div className="line">
          <hr />
        </div>
        {questions} {/*Aquí te faltaria mostrar las preguntas*/} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Un saludo!!!

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder.